# Parse a string to floats with different separators

Tags: python, numbers, floating-point

I have a number of strings that represent numbers which use commas or points to separate thousands and have different floating separators. For example:

> "22 000,76", "22.000,76", "22,000.76", "1022000,76", "-1,022,000.76", "1022000", "22 000,76$", "$22 000,76"

How can I convert these to float point numbers in Python?

In PHP I use function like this: http://docs.php.net/manual/sr/function.floatval.php#84793

Comment: Can you show us the output you need. I am getting a little confused with your example.

Comment: Example output: 22000.76, 22000.76, 22000.76, 1022000.76, -1022000.76, 1022000, 22000.76, 22000.76 - floating numbers

Comment: @Bondarenko: what about "100,000"?

Comment: @BondarenkoMikhail: What also? I think this could mean either 100000 or 100.0

Comment: Full example: "22 000,76", "22.000,76", "22,000.76", "22 000","22,000","22.000","22000.76","22000,76","1.022.000,76","1,022,000.76","1,000,000","1.000.000","1022000.76","1022000,76","1022000","0.76","0,76","0.00","0,00","1.00","1,00","-22 000,76","-22.000,76","-22,000.76","-22 000","-22,000","-22.000","-22000.76","-22000,76","-1.022.000,76","-1,022,000.76","-1,000,000","-1.000.000","-1022000.76","-1022000,76","-1022000","-0.76","-0,76","-0.00","-0,00","-1.00","-1,00"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
import locale

# Remove anything not a digit, comma or period
no_cruft = re.sub(r'[^\d,.-]', '', st)

# Split the result into parts consisting purely of digits
parts = re.split(r'[,.]', no_cruft)

# ...and sew them back together
if len(parts) == 1:
    # No delimeters found
    float_str = parts[0]
elif len(parts[-1]) != 2:
    # >= 1 delimeters found. If the length of last part is not equal to 2, assume it is not a decimal part
    float_str = ''.join(parts)
else:
    float_str = '%s%s%s' % (''.join(parts[0:-1]),
                            locale.localeconv()['decimal_point'],
                            parts[-1])

# Convert to float
my_float = float(float_str)
```

Comment: Don't use my answer if "100,000", as suggested by @Niklas B, is supposed to be 100000.

Comment: It might be interesting to use `locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']` to make sure that `float` doesn't fail when the decimal point isn't `'.'` in the current locale.

Comment: Assuming from @BondarenkoMikhail last comment (which was removed(?)) all decimal parts, if present, are supposed to consist of 2 digits. Edited my answer to reflect this fact.

Comment: I don't think using `locale` is appropriate because the input is obviously from a mixture of locales -- although it arguably it is as a guess or to provide a default interpretation...

Comment: The builtin `float()` seems not to use locale to parse a string so setting `locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']` for the decimal separator is not correct. It is better to set it to a fixed "."

Comment: Great code, I just changed ```elif len(parts[-1]) != 2:``` to ```elif len(parts[-1]) > 2:``` as I had many examples of decimal numbers with only 1 digit behind the decimal point

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have at most 2 decimal digits:

```
sign_trans = str.maketrans({'$': '', ' ':''})
dot_trans = str.maketrans({'.': '', ',': ''})

def convert(num, sign_trans=sign_trans, dot_trans=dot_trans):
    num = num.translate(sign_trans)
    num = num[:-3].translate(dot_trans) + num[-3:]
    return float(num.replace(',', '.'))
```

I test it on your example:

```
>>> for n in nums:
...     print(convert(n))
...
22000.76
22000.76
22000.76
1022000.76
-1022000.76
1022000.0
22000.76
22000.76
```